# Abelian group splits in torsion and torsion-free

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, torsion-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group.

Does the short exact sequence $0 \to TA \to A \to A/TA \to 0$ split (where $TA$ is the torsion submodule of $A$) and can one identify $A/TA$ with some submodule of the module generated by torsion-free elements?

Comment: Have you tried  $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb {Z}$?

Comment: Yes, the inclusion of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has a section using any section of $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ (and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $T\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: Have you tried with $\prod_{p} \Bbb{Z}/p \Bbb{Z}$? Its torsion subgroup should be $\bigoplus_{p} \Bbb{Z}/p \Bbb{Z}$, and I don't think it's a direct summand.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice counter-example

Comment: @Crostul Could you give at least an outline proof that it's not a direct summand? Thanks!

Comment: @DerekHolt because $$(1,1,1, \dots) = (1,0,0, \dots) + (0,1,1,1, \dots )= (1,1,0,0, \dots ) + (0,0,1,1, \dots )$$ can be written as a sum of a torsion element and a non-torsion element in two distinct ways.

Comment: I still don't see it. In ${\mathbb Z}/(3) \oplus {\mathbb Z}$, the element $(1,1) = (1.0) + (0,1) = (2,0) + (2,1)$ can be written as a sum of torsion and nontorsion elements in two distinct ways.

Comment: @DerekHolt In $G=\prod Z/pZ$, there are no nonzero divisible elements, but if $T$ is the torsion, $G/T$ is divisible. So $G/T$ does not embed in $G$, and hence it's not split.

Comment: @YCor Thanks!!!

Comment: (and more precisely $G/T$ is torsion-free divisible of continuum cardinal, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as an abstract group)